# Async function returning pending promise, despite use of await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, aws-sdk-nodejs

In the below code snippet I am trying to understand why the function does not return the result of the promise.

It first logs `Promise { <pending> }`, *then* logs the `response` variable with the correct data from the AWS API describing the table.

Why is it doing this? I've tried wrapping the function in another async function and awaiting it and I get the same result.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB;

async function describeTable() {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'weatherstation_test',
    };

    let response;
    try {
        response = await docClient.describeTable(params).promise();
        console.log(response); // This logs second. It logs the data correctly
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        throw e;
    }
    return response;
}

console.log(describeTable()); // This logs first. It logs Promise { <pending> }
```

**Update**

This still returns `Promise { <pending> }` even if I add `.then(result => result)`.

Comment: Async functions always return Promises, you might consume them with `.then`

Comment: Sorry, I should of mentioned I do not want to use `then`.

Comment: *It first logs `Promise { <pending> }`* - yes, because an `async` function *by definition* returns a Promise - it's all in the documentation

Comment: Then use async/await

Comment: async functions using await are not synchronous - they'd be called `sync` instead

Comment: This still returns `Promise { <pending> }` even if I add `.then(result => result)`.

Comment: Yeah, it won't ever *not* return a promise. It *will* return a promise. You must handle it as a promise; not as a regular function.