# Returning promise values with `then`

Tags: node.js, promise, aws-sdk-nodejs

In the below code snippet I am using `then` to get the result of a promise. However, `response` is not returned. What is returned is `Promise { <pending> }`.

I've logged `response` and can see it correctly returned the data, not a pending promise. So why is it returning a pending promise? I've even added a `then` call to the call to `describeTable`, and it still comes back pending.

I've read the following questions and they were not helpful, so please do not mark as a duplicate of them:

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

[async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482980/async-function-returning-pending-promise-despite-use-of-await)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB;

async function describeTable() {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'weatherstation_test',
    };

    let response;
    try {
        response = await docClient.describeTable(params).promise().then(result => result);
        console.log(response); // Logs the response data
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        throw e;
    }
    return response;
}

console.log(describeTable().then(result => result)); // Logs Promise { <pending> }
```

**Update**

So I've removed the first `then` (after `promise()`) because it is redundant. The answer from @libik works for me. It was the context in which `then` is run I wasn't understanding.

Comment: If you use `await` there is no need in `then` construction.

Comment: Try to remove `.then(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the asynchronous content from synchronous one.

If you want to log it, you have to do it from inside like this

`describeTable().then(result => console.log(result))`

In your case you are logging the output of asynchronous function, which is always a promise.

---

What really happens: In Node.js all the synchronous content is executed first and any asynchronous content is put to event loop to be executed later.

So first this is executed

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB;
console.log(describeTable()
```

The function is called, so then it goes inside function. Because it is asynchronous function, it will execute it synchronously till the first `await`.

```
const params = {
        TableName: 'weatherstation_test',
    };

    let response;
    try {
        response = await docClient.describeTable(params).promise()
```

Now this promise is added to Event Loop to be executed later and the function `describeTable()` returns to the synchronous context (the console log) the promise, that will be linked through all your function asynchronously later and you log this promise (which is indeed pending).

And now your synchronous context ends. Before the above promise is resolved your app can meanwhile executing other parts (which is always the same, take event from event loop, do the full synchronous part - which can push another events to event loop and then take another event and repeat)

Answer (score 1):

In order to log the result you need to write the following:

```
describeTable().then(result => console.log(result));
```